# Geometric interpretation of a generalized Euler sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Although similar arguments work for $\mathbb P^n$ for any $n$, let us deal with $X=\mathbb P^1_k$ for simplicity. Recall there is a so-called [Euler sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_sequence) on $X$ (twisted by $\mathcal O_X(1)$):
$$ 0 \to \Omega_X(1) \to \mathcal O_X \oplus \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(1) \to 0.$$
Now, consider projections $p_1,p_2:X \times_kX\to X$ and the following maps
$$p_1^*(\mathcal O_X \oplus \mathcal O_X) \to p_1^*\mathcal O_X(1), \quad p_2^*\Omega_X(1) \to p_2^*(\mathcal O_X \oplus \mathcal O_X),$$
which yields a map $p_2^*\Omega_X(1) \to p_1^*\mathcal O_X(1)$ and hence a map
$$\mathcal E:= p_2^*\Omega_X(1) \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X\times X}}p_1^*\mathcal O_X(-1) \to p_1^*\mathcal O_X(1) \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X\times X}}p_1^*\mathcal O_X(-1) = \mathcal O_{X\times_k X}.$$
Beillinson showed the map fits into the following short exact sequence ([e.g.](https://johncalab.github.io/stuff/beilinson.pdf)):
$$0 \to \mathcal E \to \mathcal O_{X\times_k X} \to \mathcal O_{\Delta} \to 0$$
where $\Delta \subset X\times_k X$ denotes the diagonal. Now, since everything is flat, we get the following distingushed triangle
$$ 
\mathcal E \to \mathcal O_{X\times_k X} \to \mathcal O_{\Delta} \to \mathcal E[1]
$$
in $\operatorname{Perf} X$ and for any $\mathcal F \in \operatorname{Perf}X$, we get the following distingushed triangle
$$
\Phi_{\mathcal E}(\mathcal F) \to \Phi_{\mathcal O_{X\times_k X}}(\mathcal F) \to \Phi_{\mathcal O_{\Delta}}(\mathcal F) \to \Phi_{\mathcal E}(\mathcal F)[1]
$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the Fourier-Mukai transform. Now, by the projection formula and flat base change (e.g. [Section III.2](https://johncalab.github.io/stuff/beilinson.pdf)), the distingushed triangle is isomorphic to the following:
$$
\oplus_{i \in \mathbb Z}H^i(X,\mathcal F(-1))[-i] \otimes_k \Omega_X(1) \to \oplus_{i \in \mathbb Z}H^i(X,\mathcal F)[-i] \otimes_k \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal F \overset{+1}{\to}. 
$$
In particular, if we apply this to $\mathcal F = \mathcal O_X(k)$ (say $k\geq 2$), then we get
$$
H^0(X,\mathcal O_X(k-1))\otimes_k\Omega_X(1) \to H^0(X,\mathcal O_X(k))\otimes_k \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(k) \overset{+1}{\to},
$$
which looks like some generalization of the Euler sequence.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this indeed a generalization of the Euler sequence in geometric sense?
2. If so, is there a nice way to obtain the triangle without using those heavy machines?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use $\Omega$ instead of $\omega$ - the latter is typically used for $\det \Omega$, which won't give you the same meaning.

Comment: Thats is true. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to obtain the triangle is the following. Consider the natural distinguished triangle
$$
H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to 
F \to
F'.\tag{*}
$$
Then $H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F') = 0$, hence $F'$ is a multiple of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$, i.e.,
$$
F' \cong V^\bullet \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1),
$$
where $V^\bullet$ is a graded vector space. Twisting this isomorphism by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$ and computing the cohomology, we check that
$$
V^\bullet \cong H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F'(-1))[1].
$$
On the other hand, twisting the triangle $(*)$ by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$, we obtain
$$
H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F'(-1)) \cong
H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F(-1)).
$$
Therefore, the triangle has the form
$$
H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to 
F \to
H^\bullet(\mathbb{P}^1, F(-1))[1] \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1).
$$

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much!